# With Ruby/Rails, how to disguise URL :id as a seemingly random 7 digit number à la basecamp.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, url-routing

I really like the Basecamp method of encoding account/user id's as a seemingly random string of 7 digit numbers to use in the URL so that no one is aware of what what database row ID they have. I have seen it specified how to do something like this by different forms of hashing or with friendly_id, but they all seem to end up having non-number characters in it as well, which I do not think looks as nice.

How can I replicate exactly how basecamp.com produces id's in a way that will "never" produce a collision?

```
https://basecamp.com/8675309
```

Comment: Exactly like you would with `friendly_id`, but limit your character set to 0..9.

Comment: https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb is also an option.

Comment: @meagar are you saying to actually use friendly_id and there is away to output only digits like i am after? i did not see anything in the documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I replicate exactly how basecamp.com produces id's in a way that will "never" produce a collision?

That is impossible. No matter what you do, no matter how clever your algorithm, it *will* produce a collision after 10000000 calls at the latest.